# cannot be resolved or is not a field in class inheritance

Tags: java

Simple java assignment: Create a class called Animal.  Give it one data item, weight.
Create two subclasses Land and Sea;  give the land animal nuberLegs;
give the sea animal number fins.
Create two subclasses under Land, Mammals and Other,  Give Mammals colorHair;
give Other hasScales.
Now create a cat, snake, frog, tuna, bear, and eel.
Print out the attributes for each animal you created.

I am currently getting errors for cat.numberLegs, cat.numberFins, cat.colorHair, and cat.hasScales saying that they cannot be resolved or is not a field. I am also pretty sure I am doing the inheritance part wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's my code for it:

```
class animal {
    String name = "cat";
    Number weight = 9;
}
class land extends animal {
    Number numberLegs = 4;
}
class mammals extends land {
    String colorHair = "brown";
}
class other extends land {
    String hasScales = "no";
}
class sea extends animal {
    Number numberFins = 4;
}
public class animalClasses {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        animal cat = new mammals();
        animal snake = new other();
        animal frog = new mammals();
        animal tuna = new sea();
        animal bear = new mammals();
        animal eel = new sea();
        System.out.println(cat.name + " is " + cat.weight + " pounds, has " + cat.numberLegs + " legs, has " + cat.colorHair + " hair.");
    }

}
```

I edited the code in response to comments and answers, but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Why do you have to create everything as an inner class?? I believe those classes shouldn;t be an inner class

Comment: If I don't nest them, then my compiler tells me to create another file, which I'm not allowed to for the assignment or take out the "public" in my animal class.

Comment: Only one class whose name the file is has to be public.. others can be just class Land, class Sea etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your instances as being one of the subclasses.

For example
animal cat = new mammals();

You have declared cat as an animal, so the only attributes it has are weight and name.

cat should be a mammals, that means it will have weight and name from animal,
numberLegs from land and colorHair from mammal.  It still will not have fins or scales because it is not sea or other.

Comment: In your example, you still declare `cat` as an `animal`, so you will still only be able to access properties of the `animal` class.  I believe the line of code you were shooting for is `mammals cat = new mammals();`.

Comment: charlie armstrong, you fixed it, you're a godsend. thanks a bunch